# Filter Repeater with Dropdown (Asp.net/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu, repeater

I Have a repeater which connects to an access database. The repeater pulls the information in using **<%# Eval("text") %>** commands and an AccessDataSource.

I am able to display the inital data fine, however I want to be able to filter the records using a series of dropdownlists. For example to be able to list only cars by "Make" "Year" "Colour". I have been able to filter the data how I want, but this is by displaying it in a second repeater and using another AccessDataSource. Ideally I would like to use just the one repeater which updates accordingly.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataFile="~/App_Data/Cars.accdb" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Cars]">
</asp:AccessDataSource>


<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/Cars.accdb" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT Make, [Year], Model, Colour, Artwork, Type, WHERE (Colour = ?)">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ColourDropdown" Name="Colour" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>




<asp:DropDownList ID="GenreDropdown" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="Colour" DataValueField="Colour"
     AppendDataBoundItems="True" CssClass="form-control"  DataMember="DefaultView"       AutoPostBack="True" >
<asp:ListItem Value="%"</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>




<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row list-group-item active">
            <div class="col-xs-2">         
            <p class="list-group-item-text active"><img src="carimages/<%#Eval("Artwork")%>" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">    
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%# Eval("Make")%> (<%# Eval("Year") %>)</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%# Eval("Model")%></p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%# Eval("Colour")%></p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%# Eval("Type")%></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> 
            </div>
          </a>
            </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>   



<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2">
<ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row list-group-item active">
            <div class="col-xs-2">         
            <p class="list-group-item-text active"><img src="carimages/<%#Eval("Artwork")%>" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">    
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%# Eval("Make")%> (<%# Eval("Year") %>)</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%# Eval("Model")%></p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%# Eval("Colour")%></p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%# Eval("Type")%></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> 
            </div>
          </a>
            </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to add parameters to the data source dynamically (that is in code behind) rather than decoratively. So in markup you should leave this (guess it was your original layout):

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
     DataFile="~/App_Data/Cars.accdb" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Cars]">
</asp:AccessDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="GenreDropdown" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="Colour" DataValueField="Colour"
     AppendDataBoundItems="True" CssClass="form-control"  DataMember="DefaultView"       AutoPostBack="True" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row list-group-item active">
            <div class="col-xs-2">         
            <p class="list-group-item-text active"><img src="carimages/<%#Eval("Artwork")%>" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">    
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%# Eval("Make")%> (<%# Eval("Year") %>)</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%# Eval("Model")%></p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%# Eval("Colour")%></p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%# Eval("Type")%></p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> 
            </div>
          </a>
            </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in code behind, say on page load, do this:

```
AccessDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("Colour", GenreDropdown.SelectedValue);
Repeater2.DataBind();
```

Comment: I tried the above, but its not accepting .Parameters. in the above code on the page_load event.

Comment: @user2904529, sorry, it should have been `SelectParameters`. Corrected

Comment: I have updated the code, but no luck. The repeater doesn't update to dropdownlist selection. I'm probably doing something wrong, but my layout/code is the same as above with the page_load code added.

Comment: @user2904529, are you sure drop down `SelectedValue` is really updated? It might be the case that it is not changing for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

you may bind to each dropdown a call to a function which retrieve data on selectedindexchanged event and re.bind your datarepeater the logic on this stuff depend from your final goal

**UPDATE**
THIS IS A SAMPLE ADAPT IT TO YOUR LOGIC

```
 Private Sub ddlsomethinhg_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlsomethinhg.SelectedIndexChanged
    //ASSUME INDEX 0 IS NOT VALID VALUE
    If ddlsomethinhg.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        //ASSUME THAT IS INTEGER
        Dim SEARCHVALUE As Integer = CInt(ddlsomethinhg.SelectedValue)
        Dim QRY As String = String.Format("select * from TABLE where colname={0}", SEARCHVALUE)
        Using cnn As New OleDbConnection("CONNECTIONSTRING")
            If cnn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cnn.Open()
            Using CMD As New OleDbCommand(QRY, cnn)
                Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(CMD)
                    Using ds As New DataSet
                        da.Fill(ds)
                        //if repeater2 is bounf in aspx page you will throw an exceptio so before you need to clean up datasource
                        Dim r As New Repeater
                        Repeater2.DataSourceID = ""
                        Repeater2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                        Repeater2.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not looking for anything complicated, just something basic that works :) thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, but your suggestion is way past my understanding. I'm looking for something similar to below if possible. Basic is fine, for what I need.

Comment: Sorry @user2904529 but it is basic :| each dropdonwlist on postback fire selecteindexchangedwhere you can and you can intercept a value so  create a new connection, new command using command to retrieve data with dataadapter and fill dataset at this point using ds binding repeater.that's all _:)